# CONSULTA CON VARIABLES DE SESION PHP , PARA CONTAR REGISTROS

Tags: php, mysql

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta para saber el número de clientes que ha registrado un usuario logeado , cuando igualo el id a un numero me resulta perfectamente como se vera en el ejemplo, pero no logro igualarlo a la variable de sesion para que funcione correctamente y muestra a los usuarios que han iniciado sesion el numero de clientes que tienen todo esto es con php, el número 3 que se ve allí es el que tiene que ir remplazado por la variable de sesion

```
 <?php 
                                $usuario_id = $_SESSION['iduser'];
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cliente.usuario_id, usuario.idusuario , COUNT(cliente.idcliente) AS Total FROM cliente inner join usuario on usuario_id =  idusuario where usuario_id = 3");
                                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                                echo ''.$row['Total'].'';
                                        ?>
```

Comment: Ejecutas `session_start();` antes de ese código, si no, ese es el problema, no se han inicializado las sesiones.

Comment: ¿Donde te puedo contactar ? @Triby

Comment: Si es relacionado a tu pregunta, aquí mismo. Si coincidimos, se puede usar el chat.